# Set integer variable through file read

Tags: c++, file-io

I know how to pass in strings from a text file. In a previous project I read in strings and then tested them on either being "t" or "f", which the result of would set a variable to true or false.

Now I am wondering if it is efficiently possible to read numbers from a text file and pass them into an `int`? All I can think of is checking for the string "1" and returning 1 in a function, but that would have to be done for every possible integer I could expect in my program, which is not an effective solution.

For context, I am trying to make a save system for a game, and `int`s/`float`s that are read in would be variables such as player health, how much of an item they have, etc.

Comment: did you happen to take a look at atoi and atof functions?

Comment: "if it is efficiently possible to read numbers from a text file" - Yes.

Comment: To start with, save the data in a textual format that is easy to output, and easy to input.  (And incidentally, easy to view and easy to edit _in situ_.) When your app outgrows that simple format, then consider something with a bit more structure that is still textual, like XML or JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know how to read a string `str` from a text file, reading numbers is not that difficult: jsut read the string as you did and use [`stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to convert the string into an `int`, or [`stof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) into `float`.

```
int i; double d; 
i=stroi(str); d=strod(str2);
```

Another technique is to use [file streams](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) to read or write from a file exactly as you would do from `cin` and `cout`:

```
ifstream file("mytext.txt"); 
file>>i>>d;
```

The previous method doesn't care so much about lines.  So still another technique is to read a string,  convert it into a string stream and use the stringstream as you would with `cin`:

```
if (getline(file, str)){   // read a full line 
    stringstream sst(str); 
    sst>>i>>d;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use stoi as you suggested, but when trying to set an integer variable to something in the text file such as "my_cool_int = stoi(my_cool_string)" where my_cool_string is a string pulled in from the text file, I get a terminate called on "std::invalid_argument". trying the same method with a custom string like "1" instead of my_cool_string doesn't get this issue. Do you know why?

Comment: @Aravash Yes, thus leans that the string does not start with a number. In this case it throws an exception that you can catch. The other alternatives do not throw an exception, but if you’d try to read an integer and no number is found, then the stream would silently fail (your integer would be unchanged/uninitialized, and all the successive reads would fail as well until you clear the error)

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::fstream`. You can open a file, and stream input or output based on how you opened the file.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    // Pretend we are passed the file location as a command-line argument to our program:

    std::fstream file { argv[1], std::ios::in };

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        int value;
        file >> value;

        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Could not open file " << argv[1] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Provided that the information is correctly formatted in the file, this should work.

I didn't run it, so there might be syntax errors, but the basics are there. Check out [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) for some help, they will have further examples.